# SQLalchemy, why flask sets Base.query?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

In the [official Flask documentation for declarative use of SQLalchemy](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlalchemy/#declarative) the following snipped is used:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////tmp/test.db', convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()
```

Now, I simply do not understand what the last line is doing. i.e. what does

```
Base.query = db_session.query_property()
```

Performs.  **Why that line is in there?**

In my app I simply use `db_session` for every database operation.  Now I have played a little with this, and found that, in the context of an interactive session or plain python script that line performs nothing!

For example this script prints `True`

```
import sqlalchemy as sq
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
eng = sq.create_engine('sqlite://')
Base = declarative_base()
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=eng))
Base.query = db_session.query_property()
Base.query
print(Base.query == None)
```

And so does this one:

```
import sqlalchemy as sq
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
eng = sq.create_engine('sqlite://')
Base = declarative_base(bind=eng)    ### the difference is here
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=eng))
Base.query = db_session.query_property()
Base.query
print(Base.query == None)
```

So I'm at a loss. The base object returned seem to have an `__setattr__` that will disallow the setting of `Base.query`.

- What that assignment should do?
- And why my tests result in `Base.query` to be assigned with a `None`?
- By default, `Base` does not have a `query` attribute, but then wouldn't be easier to simply do `Base.query = None`?

(P.S. This is all python 3.6)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`db_session.query_property` is a descriptor that returns you a `Query` based on the class you accessed it from. For instance, if you have

```
class Foo(Base):
    pass
```

then `Foo.query` is a shorthand for `db_session.query(Foo)`. Then, because it makes no sense to say `db_session.query(Base)`, `Base.query` is naturally `None`.

Comment: Wow, it makes sense now.  Heh, that's what I get from always using `db_session.query`.  Many thanks.